# Need help with this code on jQuery onmouseout of a ul element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I have created a navigation using `<UL>` and `<LI>`. On moving out of the navigation`<UL>` I want to do something.  The code that I have written is below.

Please help me with understanding why the code below is being executed when moving from one `<LI>` to other and not just when leaving `<UL>`.

```
<ul id='navigation'>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
    <li>d</li>
</ul>

#navigation li
{
   display:inline;
   float:left;   
   width:50px;
   border-right:1px solid black;
   padding:2px;
}

jQuery("#navigation").mouseout(function(){

   alert("hi"); 

});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the JQuery documentation - http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

> This event type can cause many
>   headaches due to event bubbling. For
>   instance, when the mouse pointer moves
>   out of the Inner element in this
>   example, a mouseout event will be sent
>   to that, then trickle up to Outer.
>   This can trigger the bound mouseout
>   handler at inopportune times. See the
>   discussion for .mouseleave() for a
>   useful alternative.

See [this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/prowla/nexhH/) showing [mouseout](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/).

Answer (score 2):

try [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

> The mouseleave event differs from
> mouseout in the way it handles event
> bubbling. If mouseout were used in
> this example, then when the mouse
> pointer moved out of the Inner
> element, the handler would be
> triggered. This is usually undesirable
> behavior. The mouseleave event, on the
> other hand, only triggers its handler
> when the mouse leaves the element it
> is bound to, not a descendant. So in
> this example, the handler is triggered
> when the mouse leaves the Outer
> element, but not the Inner element.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/m2679/1)